# Отправка данных в базу через ajax

Tags: ajax, php, mysql

Здравствуйте.

Я реализовал отправку данных в базу из формы через ajax и php, все прекрасно работает, НО при добавлении в базу в самой базе вместо кириллицы абракадабра, с лат. буквами, как всегда, порядок.

В чем может быть проблема? Как исправить? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.htaccess нужно добавить `AddDefaultCharset utf-8`

Comment: преогромное спасибо!!!!

Comment: А если nginx? Здесь хорошо бы не симптомы лечить, а объяснить что к чему.

Comment: уважаемый ВОРОН, я вообще не понял о чем Вы! а вариант выше проблему не решил к великому сожалению (((

Answer (score 0):

Кодировка *базы данных* должна быть utf-8. В программе, в которой вы пишите код, сохраните файлы в кодировке utf-8 (без BOM). В мета тегах тоже укажите кодировку(`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`).

Answer (score 0):

Когда вы создаете базу данных у нее кодировка по умолчанию latin1, поменяйте на utf-8. Ну и само собой следите за кодировками при подключении к базе и вводе данных в базу.

Comment: Старайтесь писать более детальные ответы. Можно включить пример кода, привести ссылки с более подробным разбором проблемы и т. п.